# FCM Data Message size limits - can't actually send full 4096 bytes of data

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send the full 4kB (4096 bytes) in the data field of a FCM Data Message. However, the FCM API will reject the request with

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

I see these results from experimenting with having different number of fields in the request

| Data JSON | Max length accepted by FCM (total lengths of keys + total lengths of values) |
| --- | --- |
| `{"a": "value"}` | 1 + 4050 = 4051 |
| `{"a": "value", "b": "value"}` | 2 + 4043 = 4045 |
| `{"a": "value", "b": "value", "c": "value"}` | 3 + 4036 = 4039 |

From the table, I can send up to 4051 bytes, instead of 4096 bytes. Adding a field reduces the maximum length by 6 bytes + length of the new field. Compacting the JSON in the request body has no effect on the maximum length accepted by FCM.

I'm puzzled

- Where's the missing 45 bytes when there's only 1 field?
- Where are the 6 bytes being used with each new field?

Answer (score 0):

From the Firebase documentation on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):

> Maximum payload for both message types is 4000 bytes

So that's indeed around 4K, but there's some overhead in the envelope that reduces it.

Comment: Is there a deterministic way to calculate the overhead?

Comment: "Maximum payload for both message types is 4000 bytes", so if you use that as the maximum you're safe. Any other approach is likely to depend on implementation details, which may change in the future.